# Handling special characters with Java and Struts 1.1

Tags: java, forms, character-encoding, struts

Problem:

A form is submitted with a text box on it. I enter a string with the (Registered Trademark) character in it using alt+0174. The (R) symbol displays in the browser correctly.

I hit submit, with a breakpoint on BaseTilesRequestProcessor (earliest possible spot that I know of to inspect the request)

If I dig into the request and find the value corresponding to the text box, it has my string with the (R) symbol in it, but immediately before the (R) it has a weird character: Â

Before I submitted this question I found the answer here: http://ianpurton.com/struts-utf-8-and-form-submissions I used that technique and it worked correctly. So my question is, why does this work? I checked request.getCharacterEncoding() before this filter was applied and it was null. What sets this property? The browser doing the submission?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the browser *could* set this property during submission, but as the link you found correctly pointed out, most browsers don't set this by default.  As a result, you get whatever the default in Struts 1 is, which clearly isn't UTF-8.  The fact that you got NULL when you checked getCharacterEncoding() confirms that the browser isn't sending any such header.